# Android emulator fails to start when using scale (Win7 x64)

Tags: android, android-emulator

My configuration is this:

- Windows 7 x64
- Eclipse Helios x64
- JDK x64
- Android SDK r06

When I try to start an emulator from Eclipse (Android SDK setup application) with the scale parameter it just fails. Second Command Prompt screen (which I think is actually a Java app) shows some exception but it closes itself right after. This is very annoying because without the scale, WVGA emulator does not fit on my laptop's screen. Any idea how to fix this?

And when I try to start an emulator from Command Prompt with the scale, it works.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to see the error log, doing it this way :
open command line window
use "cd c:/.../android-sdk/tools" with your own path
start an emulator instance from here, use the command "emulator -avd nameofyourAVD -scale 0.5" (actually you can choose a number between 0.1 and 3 which will be the factor for scaling (like in Eclipse)
Hit "Enter" and copy-past the error log here if there is one...

Comment: When I start an emulator from the command line window with the scale parameter it works fine. The problem is when I start emulator from Eclipse.

Comment: Which scale parameter did you put in Eclipse? which screen size? Did you look in Eclipse error log maybe?

Comment: From Eclipse, you can start Android SDK setup program (as if you run android.bat from tools folder). And when you start an emulator from there, you can choose device screen size and your monitor's dpi and the size parameter is calculated (it's hard to set a wrong value). Also, I don't think that Eclipse logs these errors.

Comment: No you didn't get my meaning. Which value did you put in the field "Screen Size (in)" in Eclipse when you tried to scale?

Comment: Actually, I reinstalled windows 7 on my PC, and I seem to have the same issue as you. which I didn't have on ubuntu... might be a real bug with 7?

Comment: On Ubuntu it works fine for me too. I think this should be filed as a bug.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?cursor=10014&updated=10014&ts=1280276548&can=4

Comment: This is actually my issue about a trouble with ADT plugin, nothing linked to yours. Maybe you should create yours.